# Perturbation solution Dirac equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, perturbation-theory

I'd like to know how to solve the Dirac equation with some small gauge potential $\epsilon \gamma^\mu{A}_\mu(x)$ by applying perturbation theory. The equations reads as $$(\gamma^\mu\partial_\mu-m+\epsilon\gamma^\mu A_\mu(x))\psi(x) = 0.$$

The solution up to first order is

$$ \psi(x) = \psi_0(x) +\tau\int\frac{d^4p}{(2\pi)^4}\int d^4x'\frac{e^{-ip(x-x')}}{\gamma_\mu{p}^\mu-m} \gamma^\mu A_\mu(x')\psi_0(x')+\mathcal{O}(\tau^2).$$

For which $A(x)$ is the integral analyticaly solvable?

Comment: This is a bit like asking if there is a formula for $\int f(x){\rm d}x$ where $f$ is a general function. No it's not possible to get a solution in terms of $A$ and $\psi$ without any integral.

Comment: You might go straight to the source and check out Dirac's book on QM; he does integrals like this; also RP Feynman's *Quantum Electrodynamics* tackles this sort of thing; but Winther is right, you need to specify the potentials more.  In QED, the $A_\mu$ take on special forms which make the integrals possible.

Comment: @RobertLewis: For which special $A_\mu(x)$ is the integral solvable?

Comment: @Alpha001:  I can't remember but Feynman's book is a great place to find out.  And it is (relatively) easy as well!  Good luck with it!